How to create custom URL for my RPC node?
When I run node then I can access chain from polkadotjs/apps using 127.0.0.1:8845 (ws://127.0.0.1:8845 ) endpoints. But I want something like wss://paseo.api.integritee.network to be my endpoints. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Not a substrate issue.
Link your domain name to the public IP through your domain service provider's management dashboard. Sometimes, you might need a proxy server e.g. nginx.

@AurevoirXavier what is domain service provider's management dashboard?

By proxying it with an ssl enabled proxying webserver, see this question for tips
